# LayoutInflater doesnt work

Tags: android, layout

Im building like an chat app, so I want to add elements (user picture and message) on the go to my current view. The problem is in the showMessage function, nothings happens but no error too.

Here's my code:

ChatActivity -> showMessage:

```
RelativeLayout rly = new RelativeLayout(ChatActivity.this);
rly.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View viewToAppend = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages,null);
rly.addView(viewToAppend);
```

messages XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/fede" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
     android:text="messagetext" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

Adding setContentView(rly); works, but replace all the content with the "xml loaded", i want to append it, not replace all.

Comment: where you refer for RelativeLayout in your code ?

Comment: hmm, don't understand what you mean with "referer", that's all my code for that function

Answer (score 0):

You may be try like codes. such as

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

May be work successfully. Best of luck!

Comment: May be works now, because i edit this codes. please try again

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a layout to the inflater you can just use the inflate method with the layout id as the parameter.

---

```
    View v = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE )).inflate(R.layout.info_window_adapter_layout, null);
```

Where context the the reference to the activity context

Answer (score 0):

You create a new RelativeLayout and add the messages view to it, but you never attach the RelativeLayout to the content view. Assign your main layout an id (such as 'main_layout') in your layout xml, then add this:

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
mainLayout.addView(rly);
```

Comment: Thaks, but if I add setContentView(rly), replaces all the content with the new XML, i want to append it, not replace.

Comment: Then you need to append rly to the current content view. Specify an id in your main layout XML, and then find that view by id in your code and append rly to it.